# What is record type usages in .net 5?

Tags: c#, .net-5

What is the usage of `record` that is introduced in .net 5.
Does it have any special usage?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/

Comment: https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/08/19/asp-net-core-5-make-your-options-immutable/

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides an explanation in one of their dev blogs regarding to .NET 5.0.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-1/#c-9-records

Documents page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records

In short it enables you to create immutable data types.

Comment: To be precise the shorthand form sets all properties as immutable, or when using the long form it depends on whether you specify `init` or not. Also `init` is not unique to records, it can be applied to classes as well.